# Assigning to a Temporary Dictionary Then Final Dictionary - Advantage?

Tags: python

I'm analyzing the update function in the Issue class here: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/master/jira/resources.py

What I don't understand about the below code is the advantage of assigning twice when the developer could have simply said `data['fields] = fields` and in the else `data['fields'] = {}`

Are there any known advantages to the below?

```py
if fields is not None:
   fields_dict = fields
else:
   fields_dict = {}
data['fields'] = fields_dict

if update is not None:
   update_dict = update
else:
   update_dict = {}
data['update'] = update_dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer wanted to support `None` values and switch them to empty dictionaries. However, this could have easily been done using lines like this:

```
data['fields'] = fields or {}
```

or

```
data['fields'] = {} if fields is None else fields
```

Why do it the way it was done? Most likely the developer was just inexperienced.

Comment: I just toyed around with your first option as I hadn't seen anything like that and didn't trust it.  That is a very nice line of code that I will have to keep in mind for future use!

Comment: _"Most likely the developer was just inexperienced"_ - at least inexperienced with writing Pythonic code. In many other popular languages, the approach shown in the OP is the only way to do this.

Comment: Even in other languages the code could be simpler; the intermediate variable can be dispensed with in most.